# c++ hex game: simulation not working when using multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am implementing a monte carlo simulator for the HEX game (it is an assignment of a Coursera class I am following). 
I have a board, that holds the rocks that have a color. WHITE and BLACK color means that the position is used, GREY that it is still available.

I have a Player that is an abstract class that I specify for human and computers players differently. 
It looks something like this:

```
template <class Board>
class AiPlayer : public Player<Board> {
    using Player<Board>::_color;
    using Player<Board>::_board_ptr;
    std::mutex board_mutex;
    public:
        void simulate (const std::pair<int, int>&, const Color, std::vector<double>& wins);
        AiPlayer(const Color c):Player<Board>(c) {}
        AiPlayer(const Color c, std::shared_ptr<Board> board):Player<Board>(c, board) {}
        virtual void play();
};

template <class Board>
void AiPlayer<Board>::play()
{
    //each thread start from a different starting point
    std::array<std::thread, _N_THREADS> threads;
    std::size_t N = _board_ptr->X()*_board_ptr->Y();
    Color opponent_color = _color == Color::WHITE ? Color::BLACK : Color::WHITE;
    std::vector<double> wins(N, 0);


    int t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _board_ptr->X(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < _board_ptr->Y(); ++j) {
            if (_board_ptr->rock(i,j).color() == Color::GREY) {
                auto start_position = std::make_pair(i,j);
                //std::cout << t <<": starting simulation from " << start_position << std::endl;
                threads[t++] =std::thread(&AiPlayer<Board>::simulate,
                        this, std::ref(start_position),
                        opponent_color, std::ref(wins));
                if (t == _N_THREADS ||
                    (i == (_board_ptr->X() - 1) && j == (_board_ptr->Y() - 1))) {
                    for (int tt = 0; tt < t; ++tt) {
                        threads[tt].join();
                    }
                    //std::cout << "joining threads" << std::endl;
                    t = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    double max_val = 0; size_t max_idx = 0;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < wins.size(); ++i) {
        if(max_val < wins[i]) {
            max_val = wins[i];
            max_idx = i;
        }
    }
    auto i = max_idx/_board_ptr->Y();
    auto j = max_idx % _board_ptr->Y();
    _board_ptr->add_rock(i, j, Rock(_color));
    std::cout << std::make_pair(i,j) << ": " <<
        _board_ptr->rock(i, j) << std::endl;
    return;
}


template <class Board>
void AiPlayer<Board>::simulate (const std::pair<int, int>& start,
        const Color opponent_col, std::vector<double>& wins)
{
    Board local_board(*_board_ptr);

    local_board.add_rock(start.first, start.second, Rock(_color));
    assert(local_board.rock(start.first, start.second).color() != Color::GREY);

    std::size_t N = local_board.n_free();
    using std::vector;
    vector<std::pair<int, int>> free_pos(N);
    vector<Color> free_pos_color(N);
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < local_board.X(); ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < local_board.Y(); ++j) {
            if (local_board.rock(i,j).color() == Color::GREY) {
                assert(!(i == start.first && j == start.second));
                free_pos[k] = std::make_pair(i,j);
                free_pos_color[k] = k & 0x01 ? _color : opponent_col;
                ++k;
            }
        }
    }
    assert(local_board.rock(start.first, start.second).color() != Color::GREY);

    //generate random permutation of colors for the free postions
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    //int wins = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        std::shuffle(free_pos_color.begin(), free_pos_color.end(), g);
        for (std::size_t k = 0; k < free_pos.size(); ++k) {
            assert(!(free_pos[k].first == start.first &&
                        free_pos[k].second == start.second));
            local_board.add_rock(free_pos[k].first, free_pos[k].second, 
                    Rock(free_pos_color[k]));
        }
        //clean up
        auto l = start.first*local_board.Y() + start.second;
        assert(local_board.rock(start.first, start.second).color()  != Color::GREY);
        wins[l] += local_board.winner() == _color ? 1 : 0;
        assert(local_board.rock(start.first, start.second).color()  != Color::GREY);
        for (std::size_t k = 0; k < free_pos.size(); ++k) {
            assert(!(free_pos[k].first == start.first &&
                        free_pos[k].second == start.second));
            local_board.add_rock(free_pos[k].first, free_pos[k].second, 
                    Rock(Color::GREY));
        }
    }
    //remove initial move
    assert(local_board.rock(start.first, start.second).color()  != Color::GREY);
    local_board.add_rock(start.first, start.second, Rock(Color::GREY));
```

}

When it is single thread, there is no issues. When I start using a larger number of threads, I get some weird error. For instance, the asserts in simulate randomly fail. I do not understand what is the problem, since the global variable _board_ptr is only read by the threads (I tried also to lock, but it does not help) and wins is update only for the specific start position each thread is simulating.

It seems that problem is with the local variables. For instance, when I check for the color of the elements of the local_board it is not what it should be or the coordinates of the pair held by free_pos are equal to the starting position. I have several time the same asserts into the code, and sometime, one of the randomly fails.

Is not the life of these variable limited to the life of the thread itself? Any idea about what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When the global board is copied into the local board inside each thread, what guarantees can be made regarding CPU cache coherency?  This is if the global board is populated by CPU-1 and then read by a thread on CPU-2 will it read the state correctly?  Not saying this is the problem, but try putting a memory fence inside the start of the thread proc.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I tried adding `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);` at the beginning or each thread or before spawning each thread and it di not help. For debugging purpose I also tried to add a return right after the first assert and some time it fails. I think the problem is with the variables local to the threads.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. I was passing `start_pos` by reference and this was changed by the main thread.